# How to use the TranscribeStreamingClient in the browser with credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, amazon-transcribe

I want to be able to offer a RT transcription in my browser app using AWS transcribe. I see there is the `TranscribeStreamingClient` which can have credentials for AWS which are optional - I assume these credentials are required for access to the s3 bucket?

What I want to know is how to setup auth in my app so that I can make sure my users dont go overboard with the amount of minutes they transcribed?

For example:

*I would be expecting to generate a pre-signed url that expires in X seconds/minutes on my Backend that I can pass to the web client which it then uses to handle the rest of the communication (similar like S3).*

However I don't see such an option and the only solution that I keep circling back to is that I would need to be feeding the audio packets from to my backend which then handles all the auth and just forwards it to the service via the streaming client there. This would be okay but the documentation says that the TranscribeStreamingClient should be compatible for browser integrations. What am I missing?